# angular form.io form-builder custom component get reference

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formio

I'm developing in ANGULAR 10

I use form.io form-builder to render components

I add custom component that drow grid (ag-grid) According to this link [add custom Components with Angular Elements](https://github.com/formio/angular-formio/wiki/Custom-Components-with-Angular-Elements)

every think work well

I drag and drop the table several times to draw multiple tables.
I enclose a photo of how the form looks like after the drag and drop action into the form

[image]

The problem .

when form.io render my custom component that draw the ag-grid , i need to get the connection string and the sql statement from the component definition (json).

I do not know how to get this information from my custom component at the time it's be rendering.   Without this information, I do not know generate the column names and row's content.

> This is my project

**builder component contain the formio tag**

**aggrid component is my custom component for display ag grid**

[image]

> formio.ts

import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { FormioCustomComponentInfo, registerCustomFormioComponent } from 'angular-formio';
import { AggridWrapperComponent } from './aggrid-wrapper.component';

```
export function minimalEditForm() {
  return {
    components: [
      { key: 'type', type: 'hidden' },

      
      {
        weight: 10,
        type: 'textarea',
        input: true,
        key: 'key',
        label: 'sql statement',
        tooltip: 'please enter your sql statement',
      }
    ],
  };
}
const COMPONENT_OPTIONS: FormioCustomComponentInfo = {
  type: 'sqlaggrid',
  selector: 'sql-grid',
  editForm: minimalEditForm,
  title: 'sql-grid',
  group: 'basic',
  icon: 'fa fa-star',
};



export function registerAgGridComponent(injector: Injector) {
  registerCustomFormioComponent(COMPONENT_OPTIONS, AggridWrapperComponent, injector);

}
```

> aggrid-wrapper.component.html

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
   [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

> AggridWrapperComponent

```
    import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, ElementRef, Output ,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
    import { FormioCustomComponent } from 'angular-formio';
    
    
    import { Grid, GridOptions } from "ag-grid";
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-aggrid-wrapper',
      templateUrl: './aggrid-wrapper.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./aggrid-wrapper.component.css']
    })
    
    export class AggridWrapperComponent implements FormioCustomComponent<number>  {
      @Input()
      value: number;  //number is missing (null)
    
      @ViewChild('aggrid') input; 
    
      @Output()
      valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
    
      @Input()
      disabled: boolean;
    
      private _value: number;
    
    
    
     
      public gridOptions: GridOptions;
    
      constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
          columnDefs: this.createColumnsDefs(),
          onGridReady: (params) => {
            this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.executeStatement());
          }
        }
      }
     
      createColumnsDefs() {
    
        /* return the grid columns */

       /*If I could get the field definition containing the SQL statement   then I could return the columns of the grid */
        return ???;
      }
    executeStatement(){
    
    /* get the grid rows  */
/*If I could get the field definition containing the SQL statement   then I could execute the statement and back the rows  */
    return ??? */
    
    }
    
    }
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule ,Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {AppConfig} from './formio-config';
//import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'
import { FormioModule } from 'angular-formio';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BuilderComponent } from './builder/builder.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { RatingWrapperComponent } from './rating-wrapper/rating-wrapper.component';
import { registerAgGridComponent} from './aggrid-wrapper/formio'
import { AggridWrapperComponent } from './aggrid-wrapper/aggrid-wrapper.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';


import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({


  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BuilderComponent,
    AggridWrapperComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    FormioModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgbModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule{

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    registerAgGridComponent(injector)
  }
}
```

I am missing the reference to the component definition

any idea ?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this ?. I am also trying to use ag grid inside an angular custom component.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried getting the object by its key?

```
component = form.getComponent('keyName')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

1. from Where did the form object come from.
2. I drag and drop the same component several times,   and I do not know within the component (AggridWrapperComponent) which instance I am.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was able to achieve by creating a Subject and pushing the data at the OnChange of App Component and then retrieving where ever I want to.

Comment: Please include and show _how_ you did the thing not just "I did a thing and it worked"